# How can I insert or update if a value is different?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write an SQL query that will set a value to 1 when it updates another column.

Specifically, I want to set my is_patch_file to 1 if the corresponding hash column is changed. If the hash column is NOT changed, it should keep whatever the currently stored is_patch_file value is.

Is this possible?

**Table Structure**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `program_files`;
CREATE TABLE `program_files` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `folder_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_patch_file` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_file` (`folder_id`,`name`,`path`,`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

**SQL Queries**

```
INSERT INTO program_files (folder_id, name, path, hash, is_patch_file, enabled, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (3, 'TestName', 'TestPath', 'TestHash', 0, 1, NOW(), NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
is_patch_file=1, #Is Patch file should ONLY be 1 if the hash is different from the original hash...otherwise keep our current value how do I do this?
hash=VALUES(hash),
updated_at=VALUES(updated_at);

INSERT INTO program_files (folder_id, name, path, hash, is_patch_file, enabled, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (3, 'TestName', 'TestPath', 'TestHash2', 0, 1, NOW(), NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
is_patch_file=1, #Is Patch file should ONLY be 1 if the hash is different from the original hash...otherwise keep our current value how do I do this?
hash=VALUES(hash),
updated_at=VALUES(updated_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare `hash` to `VALUES(hash)` before it gets updated, and use that when setting `is_patch_file`.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    is_patch_file = hash != VALUES(hash), 
    hash = VALUES(hash), 
    updated_at = VALUES(updated_at)
```